# Flattening an array so first item is key

Tags: php, arrays, flatten

Is there a way to flatten this array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [country_code] => IM 
        [language_code] => GB 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [country_code] => GG 
        [language_code] => JE 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [country_code] => US 
        [language_code] => US 
    ) 
)
```

to this:

```
array (
    "IM" => "GB"
    "GG" => "JE"
    "US" => "US"
)
```

I need to have the first item from each to be the key, and the second item the value.

**Update**

Is it possible to have multiple values using the secon concept. If I had this array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [country_code_two] => GBR [country_code_three] => GB [language_code] => EN ) )
```

and wanted to create the following:

```
array (
    [GBR] => array ([0] => "GB", [1] => "EN")   
)
```

How would this be possible? I am currently using your second option as I dont have 5.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using PHP 5.5, you can do this: ([Docs](http://php.net/array-column))

```
$result = array_column($source, "language_code", "country_code");
```

If you aren't using PHP 5.5, then you should be :p

More seriously, a backwards-compatible version:

```
$keys = array_map(function($a) {return $a['country_code'];},$source);
$vals = array_map(function($a) {return $a['language_code'];},$source);
$result = array_combine($keys,$vals);
```

And if you're somehow stuck on a *really* old vesion of PHP, the "traditional":

```
$result = array();
foreach($source as $a) {
    $result[$a['country_code']] = $a['language_code'];
}
```

Comment: On the second way, is it possible to create an array inside the key of two items?

Comment: Sorry, I have added to the question to hopefully help explain better.

Comment: In that case yes, just `return` the array you want.

Comment: $keys = array_map(function($a) {return $a['country_code_two'];},$codes);
  $vals = array_map(function($a, $b) {return $a['country_code_three']; $a['language_code'];},$codes);
  $result = array_combine($keys,$vals);

Comment: `return array($a['country_code_three'],$a['language_code']);`